# Can't Sync m4b files to iPod

Tags: macos

My m4b audiobook will NOT sync to my ipod. Can play in iTunes but shows up grayed out in the list. Why?

iPod 5th gen and iTunes latest

Answer (score 1):

In iTunes, what happens if you select that m4b, then look at "Create New Version" in the menu?

[image: menu]